# Client not receiving anything from socket server

Tags: python, java, sockets

**When I'm trying to receive data from the server, nothing happens and the code is still blocked. What am I doing wrong?**

> **Client.py**

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 30000
MESSAGE = "message"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(bytes(MESSAGE, encoding='utf8'))
    print(f"Connected at {HOST}:{PORT}..")

    data = s.recv(1024) # this is the line of code which is blocking it
    print(data)
    s.close()
```

> **Server.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server{

    public static final int PORT = 30000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        System.out.println("Listening on port "+PORT+"..");

        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        
        String message = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);
        
        out.println("ccc");
    }

}
```

**I tried communication between python client and python server, java client and java server, both was working, but this doesn't work..**

Comment: Java is trying to read a *line* of text (because you called `readLine()`), but you never send a newline character `\n`.

Comment: Omg, tysm, you are the best!